# Return 201 Created status with specific body in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, springfox

I have defined the following REST endpoint in my Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/data",
        consumes = { "application/json" },
        produces = { "application/json" })
@ResponseBody
public Mono<ServerResponse> create(
        final @ApiParam(value = "data", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody Data data) {

    Data saved = dataDAO.save(app);
    return saved != null
            ? ServerResponse.created(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("data/" + saved.getId()).build().toUri()).
                    contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                    body(BodyInserters.fromObject(saved))
            : Mono.error(new CustomException("Error"));
}
```

but when I call `/data` I obtain an `Error: Not Acceptable`:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1562229060618,
  "path": "/data",
  "status": 406,
  "error": "Not Acceptable",
  "message": "Could not find acceptable representation"
}
```

so I think there is some problem in the definition of my endpoint, because at the end the data is correctly created in my DB.

What am I doing wrong? And what is the right way to return a 201 Created status with the body I want (`Data` type)?

Is that error related to the fact that it does not recognize a valid data to return?

Thanks

Comment: are you sending `content-type` header as `application/json` in your request?

Comment: well you can use `ResponseEntity` with some logic to make it work

Comment: @sidgate yes I am sending it

Comment: @emotionlessbananas do you have an example please?

Comment: you want us to help you with your faulty call, when you dont even post what your call looks like? Clap

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question i have no idea, because you havn't posted what your request looks like or what your `Data` object looks like so it could be anything. Kind of hard to solve things when you don\t have the entire picture.

But i'm going to answer your second question:

> what is the right way to return a 201 Created status with the body I want (Data type)?

```
Data saved = dataDAO.save(app);
```

This above , is a blocking call. It will call your database and wait until it gets your `Data` object back.

Since i have no idea what database you are using, but this call should be wrapped in a `Mono.fromCallable` so that this blocking call will get its own thread from the `elastic` thread pool as per the reactive documentation [wrap blocking call](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking)

```
return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    return dataDAO.save(app);
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
  .flatMap(data -> {
      return ServerResponse.ok().syncBody(data);
});
```

I have no idea whats in your dao so i won't write any error handling, but i would return an optional and not `null` from it, much cleaner.